# My custom validator is not working, reactive forms Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am trying to validate an input that check if the article that i am registering exists or not... so... i have a method that check in my database, then i set in a variable a boolean value.

Then i pass this variable to the validator... but something is not working.

VALIDATION FUNCTION:

```
   validateRef(controlref: boolean): ValidatorFn {
    return () => {

        if ( controlref == true  ) {
            return { 'validref': true };
        } 

        if (controlref == false) {
          return { 'validref': false}
        }
    };
```

MY FORM:

```
  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) {

    this.createForm();

  }

  createForm() {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      ref: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateRef(this.controlref)]],
    })
  }
}
```

The variable that i am passing to the function, i've checked and is working... but the this.data.controls.ref.errors is always null.

HERE [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ks6wis)

can you guys guide me with this? thank you

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: i am still trying to fix it, and i have an update... if I initialize the variable that i pass to True, the form this.dataform.controls.ref.errors = true;
so... i dont understand ^^

Comment: @Chellappan let me do it

Comment: @Chellappan https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6d7b6

Comment: the stackblitz is showing properly

Answer (score 0):

HTML

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7zzbm5)

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
    <input placeholder="Enter Something" formControlName="ref">
    <div *ngIf="dataForm.get('ref').hasError('invalidRef')">
        the data is not entered
    </div>
</form>
```

component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      ref: ['', [Validators.required, CustomvalidatorService.validateRef]],
    })
  }
```

custom-validator.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Injectable()
export class CustomvalidatorService {

  constructor() { }

  static validateRef(control: FormControl) {
    if (!control.value) {
      return { 'invalidRef': true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. But... it is not solving my problem, as you can see in my DEMO. i have to have the posibility to change into true/false the value.
I will receive from a parametre a variable with a boolean value. and depending the value.. the result must be { valueRef: true } or { valueRef: false }

Comment: you need to update control value. to update you custom valdation

Comment: That exactly what i need... can you please guide me with it?

Comment: You can use my stackblitz

Comment: Sorry @UnluckyAj but i cant give you it as valid answer... i was checking again your DEMO and what you are doing is simply checking if there is any value in the input.
What i pretend is, depending of the value of 'controlRef' the validator 'invalidRef' change to true/false.

Comment: every thing depends on form control u need to update there is no need of 'controlRef'.

Comment: but how can i control it, if the value of the variable that i have to check is outside the formcontrol? i think... i am not explaining it well sorry... I just want... that { invalidRef: } is true or false depending of controlRef value

Comment: thats why reactive form is used. at any point if your value is incorrect it will give you vaidation error. you just update your control value and check

Comment: i insist... i think i dont explain it well.. my validation should not depends on control.value or value... my validation should depends of my variable controlRef...

Comment: which type of validation you want i mean 'required', 'pattern'??

Comment: i dont care the type.... i just want that depending of the value of my variable  controlRef: boolean, my form will be valid or not....

Comment: i got you problem let me give you example

Comment: at least, the value is changing now, but as you see is not returning false... but i will keep working on it! thank you, you gave me an idea about how to keep working :P

Comment: but it will return always false if you remove validation.

Comment: it will give false if you give value to input field.

Comment: but now i understand something, you have to have a return null or your form will never be valid... uhmmm interesting :P i will let you know when i find a final solution. thanks a lot